# Webpages not loading in 12.04

Tags: 12.04

after upgrading to ubuntu 12.04 lts browser (firefox, chrome) does not load webpages. 
Connection to the network works and also to the internet (skype is working)
Software installaion via sudo apt-get fails ( -5 hostname association ...)

Comment: This seems like it's caused by a bad HTTP proxy server, since both `apt-get` and your web browser use HTTP, but Skype does not. Hopefully someone with extensive experience using and troubleshooting HTTP proxies on Ubuntu can post an answer...

Comment: I have been going crazy with this same issue. I found this possible solution having to do with turning off ipv6 but it did not help me http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978398

Comment: What do you get you you type `traceroute google.com` in terminal?

Answer (score 2):

This could be to do with your DNS settings. Are you getting any error messages back from either browser or terminal?

You should pick up your DNS setting from your router/default gateway which in turn picks it up from your ISP.  Try editing the connection to use a external DNS.  One that I always use is 8.8.8.8 and secondary of 8.8.4.4 which are run by Google. Other options available are OpenDNS.

Ideally this would be some that would be programmed into your router so that your whole network behaves the same other you may have to fix this on each workstation.

Note: This can have issues on your local network if you need to resolve something internally.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this might not be the answer that you're looking for, but since I don't have the outcome of `traceroute google.com`, I will suggest some things that you can try.

- Disable IPV6
- Change default DNS to Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)
- Try pinging ubuntu.com and both Google DNS Servers (8.8.8.8
  and 8.8.4.4)
- Check to see if Java is installed properly
- uninstall Chrome, and install Chromium.  `sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable`, and  install Chromium from the Ubuntu Software Centre.
- Check to see if flash is installed properly
- DNS prefetching

> DNS prefetching is performed to resolve domain names to IP addresses
>   while loading web pages.  To disable DNS prefetching, create a new
>   Boolean preference named `network.dns.disablePrefetch` in
>   `about:config` and set it to true, as follows:
>
> ```
>     Type about:config in the address bar, press Enter.
>     Context click (right-click) in the preferences list and select "New -> Boolean".
>     Type or paste in the preference name network.dns.disablePrefetch and click OK.
>     Select true as the value and click OK. 
> If this doesn't help you can re-enable DNS prefetching by resetting the preference to "false" (double-click to toggle).
> ```
>
> <sup>Source:Mozilla</sup>

- Managing DNS Entries

To manage DNS entries, you can modify DNS names from the `/etc/resolv.conf` file

Comment: Why remove chrome and install chromium?

Comment: Chromium is the base for chrome.  Chrome is the Chromium open source project built, packaged, and distributed by Google.

Answer (score -3):

=>Clear all the browser related items like cookies, history and bookmarks.

or

if first one is not working then follow second.

=>Make an installation of your browser again. remove your existing installed browser.It will help you to cover all those files which are corrupting your browser.

Comment: `apt-get` is not working, so why would you expect anything specific to a web-browser to help this problem?